# Flutter - Widget best practices in regards to circular dependency

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns, widget, flutter-widget

What is the available recommended approaches / design patterns / bestpractices to Flutter Widgets regarding circular dependency? I mean most of them should be clean I guess, but sometimes there's probably an advantage in already using another custom Widget inside another one. Which begs the question since a Widget is a Widget in a Widget - how do you prevent (in code / design / best practices / naming conventions, etc) this behavior:

```
class TestWidget1 extends StatelessWidget
{
  const TestWidget1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TestWidget2();
  }
}

class TestWidget2 extends StatelessWidget
{
  const TestWidget2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TestWidget1();
  }
}
```

And still maintain reusability. So that whenever you add a certain Widget inside another Widget it still retains the look of how they look anywhere else. Or what are the valid approaches to Flutter Widget design? Because once I've designed how my "Widget 1" looks I want to reuse that code whenever possible without worrying about loops.

Using naming conventions / for the files are no sure way / non enforable and might look weird:

```
-- DIR widgets
---- DIR reusable (stateless?)
------ FILE header_widget.dart
------ FILE content_widget.dart
------ FILE image_widget.dart
---- DIR non_reusable (stateful?)
------ FILE header_and_content_widget.dart
------ FILE header_and_image_widget.dart
```

Comment: In practice this never should happen? When would you ever have circular dependency between widgets? And if for some weird reason you do write it, you would see it crashes right away and realize that you are making a mistake

Comment: Widget inside Widgets. So if you're on screen A you want your widgets to look the same as on screen B. So, recreate Row(Text("Title"), Text("Subtitle")) whenever we need a Title + Subtitle? Then whatever style we set on them needs to be added again and again... And some of them might support children that are unknown at code time but might cause runtime errors. HeaderAndContent({required Widget? child})? Whose to say that someone can't  write code to add Widget A that adds Widgets B that adds Widget A without knowing it? Unless you have rules or something to warn against it while coding.

Comment: It just doesn't make any sense to do it. It has nothing to do with looking the same. You logically would never do this

Comment: No one said anything about doing this - just best practices about preventing it can happen. Because it can still happen at runtime. Looking the same = Actually programming and preventing spagetti code of having the same code again and again when the same Widget (or "Look") is used a 100 times in an app. Therefor putting the same Widgets into their own classes but preventing them from adding specific Widgets as children or likewise. I guess circular dependency is non existing in Flutter then since it's logically impossible. Good to know.